# Ask Different formatting bug in election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election, ask-different

It seems like the [stats for the elections](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election) are creeping up the side of the results:

[image]

Apologies for the awful circles. Trackpads are not meant for this sort of exercise.

Comment: Your circles are freehand so that is allowed!

Comment: Yep, there's a `<br>` missing, all right.